# Configure xfce4-screenshooter default saved file name

Tags: configuration, screenshot

The default screen shoot app on Lubuntu allows one to configure the file name. Can that be done with  xfce4-screenshooter? How?

A default saved file name looks like:

```
Screenshot_2021-03-25_10-32-42.png
```

I do not see it in the help:

```
me@it:~$ xfce4-screenshooter  -h
Usage:
  xfce4-screenshooter [OPTION…]

Help Options:
  -h, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -c, --clipboard          Copy the screenshot to the clipboard
  -d, --delay              Delay in seconds before taking the screenshot
  -f, --fullscreen         Take a screenshot of the entire screen
  -m, --mouse              Display the mouse on the screenshot
  -o, --open               Application to open the screenshot
  -r, --region             Select a region to be captured by clicking a point of the screen without releasing the mouse button, dragging your mouse to the other corner of the region, and releasing the mouse button.
  -s, --save               File path or directory where the screenshot will be saved
  -i, --imgur              Host the screenshot on Imgur, a free online image hosting service
  -V, --version            Version information
  -w, --window             Take a screenshot of the active window
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```

nor in a config file, `/home/me/.config/xfce4/xfce4-screenshooter`:

```
app=firefox
last_user=
screenshot_dir=file:/home/cwhii
action=1
delay=0
region=1
show_mouse=1
```

Comment: No such option is available, file a feature request here or send a patch: https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screenshooter/-/issues/new?issue%5Bassignee_id%5D=&issue%5Bmilestone_id%5D=

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.config/xfce4/xfce4-screenshooter` set `timestamp` to `false` to disable the timestamp:

```
echo "timestamp=false" >> ~/.config/xfce4/xfce4-screenshooter
```

Next add the `title` parameter to set the file name:

```
echo "title=filename" >> ~/.config/xfce4/xfce4-screenshooter
```

Comment: This works! Too bad we can't also customize the timestamp format...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the actual question but until it is a feature of `xfce4-screenshooter` per [Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov)'s comment install the Lubuntu app:

```
sudo apt install screengrab
```

This answer to "[How do I change my keyboard shortcuts in xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/165087)" tells how to change the app invoked by <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key from `xfce4-screenshooter` to `screengrab`.